# OpenERP How to make a button invisible on button click event

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

In python, I have the following field:

```
'permit':fields.selection([('new', 'New'),
            ('applied', 'Applied'),
            ('received','Received')], 'Permit', select=True), 

def apply_permit(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        data = {'value': {'permit':'applied'}}
        return data
```

In XML, I have the following:

```
 <field name="permit" readonly="True"/>
 <button name="apply_permit" string="Apply" type="action" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible':[('permit','=','applied')]}" />
```

The attrs code above doesn't currently work but what I want to do is: when click on the button  'permit' field value will be set to 'applied' and then hide the button.All these done before the form save. The button is inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is type "action", it should be type "object".  I suspect your method isn't getting called.  Otherwise it looks fine.

The only problem is the button click is going to trigger a form save.

To do it without a form save, I would replace the button with a boolean type field calling the same on_change method as that looks fine.